# Weird noise from laptop?

Tags: laptop

I have acer e5 473g and yesterday its fell from my bed and after the laptop fell the laptop went off

And after i turn it on again the laptop stuck at acer logo didnt reach windows10 loading circle and it made a weird noise:

[Noise](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Unidi92-VAbXp5QnlGLXdZTjg/view?usp=drivesdk)

Whats wrong and can its still be fixed? Sorry if im asking at the wrong place... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your hard drive died. That clicking sound is the reader head slamming back and forth.

Comment: Died means it cant be fixed anymore? Thankyou for answering

Comment: @PanduA, if the data's important, send the drive to a data-recovery company.  Expect to pay around a thousand dollars, with no certainty that you'll get everything back.